# TypeScript: Using a class from inside an object with explict type

Tags: typescript

I'm failing to understand how I can assign a type explicitly in TypeScript from a class that is inside an object (effectively a namespace):

```
let obj = {
    hello: class {
        constructor: function () {
            console.log('hi');
        }
    }
}

// Implicit type assignment in global space works
var inst = new obj.hello();

// But explicit assignment of the type doesn't work.
var inst2: obj.hello;
function assign() {
    inst2 = new obj.hello();
}
```

[This is it on TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20hello%3A%20class%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20constructor%3A%20function%20()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('hi')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Implicit%20type%20assignment%20in%20global%20space%20works%0D%0Avar%20inst%20%3D%20new%20obj.hello()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20But%20explicit%20assignment%20of%20the%20type%20doesn't%20work.%0D%0Avar%20inst2%3A%20obj.hello%3B%0D%0Afunction%20assign()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20inst2%20%3D%20new%20obj.hello()%3B%0D%0A%7D). The output looks fine, but the typing information for `inst2` isn't available, it just falls back to `any` and I don't understand why that would be.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of the `inst` is not `hello`. It is an *anonymous class type* which you can see hovering on the `inst` in your provided example. And because it is *anonymous* you can't refer it from the code.

Comment: Good point - thank you! If I make the class named though, [it still doesn't work](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20hello%3A%20class%20hello%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor%20()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20console.log('hi')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Implicit%20type%20assignment%0D%0Avar%20inst%20%3D%20new%20obj.hello()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Explicit%20assignment%0D%0Avar%20inst2%3A%20obj.hello%3B%0D%0Afunction%20assign()%20%7B%0D%0A%20inst2%20%3D%20new%20obj.hello()%3B%0D%0A%7D).

Comment: I got it: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=namespace%20obj%20%7B%0D%0A%20export%20class%20hello%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor%20()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20console.log('hi')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Implicit%20type%20assignment%0D%0Avar%20inst%20%3D%20new%20obj.hello()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20But%20explicit%20assignment%0D%0Avar%20inst2%3A%20obj.hello%3B%0D%0Afunction%20assign()%20%7B%0D%0A%20inst2%20%3D%20new%20obj.hello()%3B%0D%0A%7D). The "trick" was to use a `namespace` rather than just an plain object. Thanks for your help!